# Table rows re-order following table update with a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

My app has a table definition as follows to manage users:

```
  Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |             Default              
-----------+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 id        | integer |           | not null | generated by default as identity
 utoken    | integer |           | not null | 
 username  | text    |           | not null | 
 password  | text    |           | not null | 
 email     | text    |           |          | 
 tos       | integer |           | not null | 0
 suspended | integer |           | not null | 0
 visible   | integer |           | not null | 1
 flags     | text    |           |          |
```

My test table has 3 records. I did an update to records 1 and 2 by:

```sql
UPDATE table
SET flags = (SELECT flags FROM table WHERE id = 3)
WHERE id IN (1,2)
```

After the update, the records based on id, were re-ordered to 3,1,2 for some reason.

Is this a result of the update or something related to the table design following the update?

Comment: Rows in a table have no implied sort order. If you need a specific order in a result the only way is to use an `ORDER BY`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So then I would need to re-write every query that hits this table and add a specific `order by`

Comment: If you want a **guaranteed** sort order, then yes.

Comment: Yes, for order, you need an ORDER BY. Without ORDER BY, there is no order.

Comment: Note that this is independent of any DML against the table. The "order" of the rows in a result (without an `order by`)  can also change because e.g. the planner decided to use a different execution plan (e.g. nested loop vs. hash join)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Interesting point for the planner part.